# Add custom list template in SharePoint 2019 modern?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is it possible to add a link to a custom list template in the "New" menu in SharePoint 2019/SE, modern UI? How? We don't want to use the old addanapp.aspx page.

Edit. By "New menu" I mean the menu found on the start page (Home.aspx).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to site settings -> site content types -> create a new content type by using Page as parent content type. Then use your custom site template in the newly created content type.

2.Go to library settings -> Versioning Settings -> Content Approval -> Set Yes.

3.Go to library settings -> content types section -> Add from existing site content types.

Comment: Thanks, but this mean I have to go to a library to create a library.  There is a similar menu on the **start page** (Home.aspx) I'd like to use! When following your instructions it makes me download the list template file itself, it doesn't create a library.